# Logic tables in python with format

Tags: python, string-formatting, logical-operators, boolean-logic

So I have a quick question in Python. 
Say, I am implementing basic logic gates in `python (AND, OR, XOR, XNOR etc)`
like this:

#### OR Gate

```
def OR(a,b):
    if a == True or b == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

#### XOR Gate or exclusive OR gate

```
def XOR(a,b):
    if a != b:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

#### XNOR Gate or the logical complement of XOR Gate

```
def XNOR(XOR):
    if XOR == True:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

1. 
*Now, I was trying to print them like this:*

```
print "AND Gate Table:"
print "A = False, B = False \t", AND(False, False)
print "A = True, B = False \t", AND(True, False)
print "A = False, B = True \t", AND(False, True)
print "A = True, B = True \t", AND(True, True)
```

*This outputs :*

```
AND Gate Table:
A = False, B = False    False
A = True, B = False     False
A = False, B = True     False
A = True, B = True      True
```

2. Well Now I thought of using `format` to print the table for me, so I did:

```
tableformat = '{:<10}' * 6
print tableformat.format("A", "True", "B", "True", ":", AND(True, True))
```

#### But to my surprise, this resulted in this

```
A         False     B         True      :         1
```

Now obviously I changed arguments say `AND(True, False)` and repeated Step 2 above and it gave me `0`.

---

### My Question:

Now, this is something interesting which I don't understand, how is it returning me boolean when I am simply printing a table, but an actual binary value when I am doing essentially the same thing, calling the same function while printing using `[format()][1]`. This is fascinating and I would love to understand how it works.

*Thanks in advance for your answer(s).*

Comment: Edit: This is what format is: [format](https://pyformat.info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `format`, it calls `True.__format__`. That method isn't implemented on the `bool` type, but `bool` inherits from `int` so the behavior is the same as an integer. That's why you get a number out.

```
>>> bool.__format__ is int.__format__
True
```

When doing a simple `print`, the `__str__` method is called instead and the `bool` class defines its own version of this method which gives you a string "True" back.

```
>>> bool.__str__ is int.__str__
False
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `bool.__format__()` decides how it is displayed:

```
>>> True.__format__('')
'True'
>>> True.__format__('<10')
'1         '
```

You can see how this mirrors the above (because it calls the above):

```
>>> '{}'.format(True)
'True'
>>> '{:<10}'.format(True)
'1         '
```

But you can avoid this by using a conversion operation, that forces `str(True)` before doing any formatting:

```
>>> '{!s:<10}'.format(True)
'True      '
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
>>> str(True).__format__('<10')
'True      '
```

Answer (score 1):

For the most parts, bool types are syntactic sugar for 0 and 1:

```
>>> 1 == True
True

>>> 0 == False
True

>>> ['item0', 'item1'][True]
'item1'

>>> True + True
2
```

One difference between numbers and bools is the return value of the `__str__()` member functions. While `(1).__str__()` returns the string '1', `(True).__str__()` returns the string 'True'. However, the format built-in calls the **format** member function.

```
>>> (1).__format__('f')
'1.000000'

>>> (True).__format__('n')
'1'
```

Numbers always return the string representation of their value, depending on the formating string. Inheritly, numbers can only formated as numbers, but not as strings

```
>>> '{:s}'.format(1)
ValueError: Unknown format code 's' for object of type 'int'

>>> '{:s}'.format(True)
ValueError: Unknown format code 's' for object of type 'bool'
```